# Redirecting with credentials to another website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, http-headers, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two websites A and B. On A I have the login option and if the user is authenticated I need to send it to B with same credentials. I have access to the code of both websites. My first approach was trying to log the user on A and figure out how could I make a Post to a action method on a controller on B(this is a recurrent question here in stackoverflow) I found this website and I don't know if it is useful: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/833007/Redirect-and-POST-in-ASP-NET-MVC. My second approach is putting all the data that I wanted to submit to B in Browser Session, call a Redirect to B and then in a method("GET") try to read all that data and check if I can proceed with the logic on B.
I want to know which is the best approach to make this happen, and also if the later is wrong or not.

I have this code on my website A:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel user)
    {
        //hardcoding InternalUser
        user.AccountType = ((int)AccountTypeEnum.Internal).ToString();
        var validator = new LoginModelValidator();

        var result = validator.Validate(user);

        if (!result.IsValid)
        {
            return View((LoginModelDecorator) user);
        }

        var service = new AuthenticationServiceAgent(user.Username, user.Password);
        var securityService = new SecurityServiceAgent(service.GeToken());

        var state = securityService.ProcessAccount(service.GeToken() != null, user.Username);

        if (state == (int)UserAccessEnum.Processed)
        {
            var type = securityService.GetAccountTypeByUser(user.Username);

            //CHeck user type
            var accountType = Enum.GetName(typeof(AccountTypeEnum), int.Parse(user.AccountType));

            var types = type.Split(',').Select(n => n.Split(':')[0]).ToList();

            var containsTheUserType = user.AccountType == "1"
                ? types.Contains("XXX") || types.Contains(accountType)
                : types.Contains(accountType);

            if (containsTheUserType)
            {
                //var cPrincipal = service.GetClaims();
                var claims = securityService.GetIdentity().Select(claim => new Claim(claim.ClaimType, claim.Value)).ToList();
                if (claims.Count != 0)
                {
                    var cPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Custom"));

                    type.Split(',')
                        .ToList()
                        .ForEach(
                            ty =>
                                cPrincipal.Identities.First()
                                    .AddClaim(new Claim("http://claims/custom/accounttype", ty)));

                    var token = new SessionSecurityToken(cPrincipal)
                    {
                        IsReferenceMode = true
                    };
                    FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SetPrincipalAndWriteSessionToken(
                        token, true);

                    Session["SEC_TOKEN"] = service.GeToken();

                    //Do I need to post?: SecurityToken, types and claims
                    //here is where I am redirecting the user
                    return Redirect("http://localhost:12345/Account/Login");
                }
                ModelState.AddModelError("LoginError", "Invalid Username or Password!");
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("AccountTypeError", "You don't have access");
        }

        switch (state)
        {
            case (int)UserAccessEnum.BlockedAccount:
                ModelState.AddModelError("StateError", "Your account is Blocked");
                break;
            case (int)UserAccessEnum.ChangePassword:
                ModelState.AddModelError("StateError", "You need to change your password");
                break;
            case (int)UserAccessEnum.NoProcessed:
                ModelState.AddModelError("StateError", "Error, please contact the system administrator");
                break;
        }

        return View((LoginModelDecorator) user);
    }
```

In my website B:

```
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        List<Claim> claims = //I need to get the claims from somewhere SESSION?
        var type = //type used in the other Loging method
        var securityToken = //securityToken used on the other Login method 

        if (claims.Count != 0)
        {
            var cPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Custom"));

            type.Split(',')
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(
                    ty =>
                        cPrincipal.Identities.First()
                            .AddClaim(new Claim("http://claims/custom/accounttype", ty)));

            var token = new SessionSecurityToken(cPrincipal)
            {
                IsReferenceMode = true
            };
            FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SetPrincipalAndWriteSessionToken(
                token, true);

            Session["SEC_TOKEN"] = securityToken;

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Any idea of how to complete the gaps that I have?

Comment: Are you using all 3 MVC  in single application ?

Comment: @EdSF Is not a single application, I have different projects and both works with MVC

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? From what you wrote it looks like you need some kind of [SSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on)

Comment: Comment wasn't meant for me :) Anyway, it's unclear what you're after - SSO? Generally speaking, I'd look into tokenization and/or simple things like signing data so both ends can validate things however they see fit.

Comment: I agree with EdSF - if you just need to establish trust between two sites you control look into [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code). Just remember to use proven libraries and don't roll your own crypto!

Comment: I am trying to achieve that(SSO). The thing is I am stuck right now, where can I point to make this happen? like a sample of code

Comment: @joozek First I need it without HMAC, then I can take a look on encrypting the data

Comment: @Zinov HMAC isn't about encrypting data it's about authenticating (signing)  and ensuring integrity

Comment: @joosek, at the moment I have a token when the user is authenticated, I am confuse because I never worked before with HMAC, can you explain me better which could be the flow for my example?

Comment: This is essentially what you're trying to achieve. Follow it: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic